# Why does referencing an item that exists in a collection view return a nil value?

Tags: ios, swift, null, uicollectionview

```
let x = X(name: "x")
blocks.append(newBlock)
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: blocks.count - 1, section: 0)
collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
let aCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
```

The above code is in a function that runs when a button is pressed in the view controller to present a new item in the collection view. As `collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])`adds a new item at the specific index, I don't understand why `let aCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell`would return a nil value. The specific error is "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I only get this error when the cell is outside of the screen. Meaning that if I add an item when there are few cells on the screen or if I scroll to the bottom if there are many cells and add a new item, it'll work. However, If there are many items and I do not scroll down, it'll have that error

Comment: Maybe it's the `as!` that's failing. Are you sure the cell is a `CollectionViewCell`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I only get this error when the cell is outside of the screen. Meaning that if I add an item when there are few cells on the screen or if I scroll to the bottom if there are many cells and add a new item, it'll work. However, If there are many items and I do not scroll down, it'll have that error.

Comment: Why do you want the cell for the item that has just been inserted?  Your `cellForItemAt` should do whatever is needed to configure the new cell

Comment: Also, your code will work but you should use `item`, not `row` when dealing with Collection Views

Comment: I realized I may be doing this wrong but I want the cell for the item that has just been inserted because I want to make the labels on the cell equal to the values of an object. So the first item's labels will be equal to one of the values of the first object in the array and so on.

Comment: As I said, this is the job of `cellForItemAt`. Just add the cell and let that data source method take care of setting the cells content when it is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618088-cellforitem) for `cellForItem(at:)` says this:

> this method returns nil if the cell isn't visible or if indexPath is out of range

You're getting a `nil` value because your cell is outside of the screen, and the force-cast is causing a crash. You should avoid force-casting in general.

**Update**

I think you might be unfamiliar with the way tables and collection views work. They don't store a cell for every row/item that you have, instead they create a pool of cells and reuse them.

When the cell goes out of bounds, the table/collection view stops associating it with the IndexPath and, as the user scrolls, this old cell is used again for the new IndexPath that needs to be displayed.

In general, you should configure your cell completely in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`, and only use `cellForItem(at:)` to update a visible cell when the content that should be displayed on it changes.

Comment: What should I do if I want to get access to the item that was just created even if it isn't visible?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the cell, but if you want to configure it you should do it when the collection view requests the new cell.

Comment: I believe I am doing this wrong but what I want is for each item in the collection view to display (using labels) the values of the corresponding object in an array. Meaning that the first item will have a label representing one of the values of the first object in the array and so on. That is why when I add an object, I want to equal its labels to the values of the object in the array.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 similar methods. `UICollectionView` implements the method `cellForItem(at:)` and the `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol defines the method `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` They do different things.

The `UICollectionView` method `cellForItem(at:)` will return a cell at the specified IndexPath if it is on screen and not out of range. It's meant for fetching cells that are currently visible.

If you call that method when the first 5 cells of your single-section collection view are visible, and ask for the indexPath of the 6th cell, you will get a nil back. That is what's happening in your code. You're trying for force cast nil to `CollectionViewCell`, so your code crashes. Don't do that. Check to see if you get back a nil, and handle nil gracefully.

If you scroll down so that cell 6 is visible and then ask for cell 6, it will be returned. If it's currently off-screen, it will return nil. As @EmilioPelaez says in his answer (voted), that's how the function works.

The other method `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` is the method the collection view calls to ask its data source to create and configure cells. That method must always return a cell for any valid IndexPath in your model. You should't call that method directly though.